# Android Espresso Accessibility Check Failing

Tags: android, android-espresso, accessibility

I am trying to run Espresso tests (written in Kotlin) in Android Studio with the **AccessibilityChecks** enabled as documented [here](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/espresso/accessibility-checking.html).

[image]

When I try using AccessibilityChecks within the tests, I get the following error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/common/base/Preconditions;
at android.support.test.espresso.accessibility.AccessibilityChecks.enable(AccessibilityChecks.java:80)
```

If I try moving it to a Before class like mentioned in the documentation:

[image]

Then it will fail with the error '*Empty test suite*':

[image]

Comment: Could you please check your dependencies with `./gradlew dependencies` for duplicated guava entry?

Comment: Added force 'com.google.guava:guava:20.0'  but still same errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two issues reported here:

> - Package    'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-accessibility:3.0.0' uses 
>     a Guava class but does not declare a dependency to Guava, resulting
>     in the errors reported in comments #1-#5.
> - Package    'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-accessibility:3.0.1'
>     seems to have duplicates of the
>     android/support/test/espresso/accessibility/R class, resulting in the 
>     error in

**Both issues have been fixed and will be included in the 3.0.2-alpha2 release**

If any issue persists, please report at [Google issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/65486414) they will re-open to examine.

Answer (score 0):

I had to add to add the guava dependency to my app gradle file using:

```
androidTestCompile 'com.google.guava:guava:20.0'
```

I also opened a ticket for Android at:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/65486414